# Sort a pandas DataFrame by the results of aggregating the data (i.e. by the index() of a shorter list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table of data that I want to sort before displaying. The sorting is based upon an aggregation. In the example below I have counted a number of cars, I want to order the dataframe by the **total** number of cars per manufacturer, in ascending order, e.g. 'mercedes' followed by 'bmw' followed by 'audi'.

I want to keep all original columns - the aggregation is *only* used to determine the sorting order.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "manufacturer": ["bmw", "bmw", "bmw", "audi", "audi", "audi", "audi", "mercedes", "mercedes"],
    "color": ["red", "blue", "silver", "red", "blue", "black", "blue", "green", "white"],
    "count": [5, 4, 7, 1, 1, 9, 7, 5, 3],
    "misc": ["a", "bc", "def", "gh", "ijk", "l", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwxyz"],
})

# order manufacturers by increasing total car counts
order = list(df.groupby("manufacturer").agg({"count": sum}).sort_values(by="count", ascending=True).index)

# apply ordering to original dataframe based on manufacturer's position in 'order' list
df.sort_values(by="manufacturer", key=lambda x: x.apply(order.index))
```

Is there a more pythonic/pandas way to do this as the above feels like I'm working too hard for something that should be simple.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `transform` with `argsort`

```
out = df.iloc[df.groupby("manufacturer")['count'].transform('sum').argsort()]
Out[207]: 
  manufacturer   color  count    misc
7     mercedes   green      5    qrst
8     mercedes   white      3  uvwxyz
0          bmw     red      5       a
1          bmw    blue      4      bc
2          bmw  silver      7     def
3         audi     red      1      gh
4         audi    blue      1     ijk
5         audi   black      9       l
6         audi    blue      7    mnop
```

If descending

```
df.iloc[(-df.groupby("manufacturer")['count'].transform('sum')).argsort()]
```

Comment: And if I wanted to sort by descending count (you know how fussy clients are)? Just `[::-1]` at the end?

Comment: @mkst check the update ~